# Sliding vertical navigation menu for responsive websites jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

Has anyone seen a full vertical page navigation menu in jquery that is hidden until the user pulls on the page with their index finger from left to right to reveal the navigation? I've seen a lot of mobile applications do this (Gmail for iPhone, facebook for iphone, mail for ipad) but I thought it would be great to extend this same experience to a "responsive" design for a site I'm building so when the resoltuion is reduced based on the mobile size, the user could interact with the menu like more mobile apps are trending towards now.

Also, the idea could also extend to the "menu" button approach, when pressed it would reveal the hidden navigation, but the user could simply pull the page to the right to reveal the navigation as well. Here's a screen from the new gmail mobile app google relesently released.

[image]

Comment: I have used this - http://web-kreation.com/all/nice-clean-sliding-login-panel-built-with-jquery/ - its from the top - but you could adapt it to run from the side - and you need to update the CSS to make the content slide (its all documented on the page)

Answer (score 0):

The Design needs extensive use of 'List elements'. You would need to design in **HTML5** and use **CSS3**. Check for **Media Queries** that you'll need to trigger on Decrease in Screen resolution.